# Using Definition Lists with forms

Tags: css

I use a lot of forms in my app, and want to have a common markup (and formatting) scheme for all kinds of cases. What is also important that these forms can contain "readonly" data, so that there is only text, not some form controls.

To solve this, I have thought of definition lists, and combine them with my form elements, like so:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>The Legend</legend>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="changeable">Label A</label></dt>
            <dd><input id="changeable" value="This can be changed"></dd>
            <dt>Label B</dt>
            <dd>Readonly value</dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> ... more ... </fieldset>
    <menu><input type="submit"> ... other actions ...</menu>
</form>
```

So the big advantage would be that the markup wouldn't change with different kinds of data. Also seems semantically correct.

However, due to formatting reasons, I need to wrap each pair in a layer. So I could do it like this:

```
<dl>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <dt><label for="changeable">Label A</label></dt>
       <dd><input id="changeable" value="This can be changed"></dd>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <dt>Label B</dt>
        <dd>Readonly value</dd>
    </div>
</dl>
```

But I also could use a separate list, and use the `<dl>` as outer Layer. However this would create a lot of single lists, containing just one item, but would save me some markup:

```
<dl>
   <dt><label for="changeable">Label A</label></dt>
   <dd><input id="changeable" value="This can be changed"></dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Label B</dt>
    <dd>Readonly value</dd>
</dl>
```

So, the question is: does this make sense and is still valid HTML5? Or would there be better options for expressing a mixed form that contains editable elements as well as "read only" elements? Would be important for me that the solution uses more or less the same layout and markup, and still makes sense from a semantic standpoint.

Comment: Looks to me like you should use a table, which *can* be valid assuming the form is structured as a series of name-value pairs.

Comment: Yeah, but with tables I would loose semantics, plus gain some potential issues with CSS formatting. Since I really only have pairs of information (eg "label" / "value"), a DL seemed more appropriate.

Comment: No semantics would be lost in a table if you use `th[scope="row"]` elements to wrap the labels.

Comment: Ok, but what if I simply do not want to use tables? Would be the construct from above OK?

Comment: I can’t see a definition list making much sense here. Labels _describe_ form elements, so that the user knows what to fill them with. That does not make the label a _term_ to _be_ defined, nor does it make the input field the “definition” of it.

Comment: @CBroe, I can see the confusion. Unfortunately `dl` is poorly named for the semantics it now has. ["The dl element represents an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list)."](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-dl-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is invalid, you can't have `div` elements as direct children of `dl` elements.

Ideally you'd be able to just use `dl`, `dt`, and `dd` elements as-is, with flexbox to align the elements, but unfortunately flexbox isn't cross-browser compatible enough for me to recommend it as a solution (yet, give it 3-5 years).

If you're going to use `<dl>` elements, you should be leaving it as one consistent list, because the items belong together as part of the same list:

```
<dl>
  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>
  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>
  ...
</dl>
```

When I see a structure as:

```
<parent>
  <wrapper>
    <key>
    <value>
  </wrapper>
  <wrapper>
    <key>
    <value>
  </wrapper>
  ...
</parent>
```

I immediately think of using a `<table>`:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">...</th>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">...</th>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But that's only because the data is tabular.

If you want to avoid the CSS nightmare that is tables (and I don't blame you if you do), then I'd suggest sticking with `<div>` elements to produce the structure you want.

```
<div class="fields">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="key">...</div>
    <div class="value">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="key">...</div>
    <div class="value">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

`<div>` elements are semantically meaningless by themselves, so if you're still interested in conveying meaning along with those elements, I recommend adding [ARIA roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles).

I believe an appropriate role for this case would be [grid](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#grid)

```
<div role="grid">
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">...</div>
    <div role="gridcell">...</div>
  </div>
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">...</div>
    <div role="gridcell">...</div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

This will give you similar semantics to an HTML `<table>`*, while also giving you the flexibility of `<div>` elements in CSS.

It's important to remember that `<label>` and `<input>` elements will semantically link to each other, so even without the ARIA roles, it will be understood that the form fields are paired together.

<sub>* Unfortunately there isn't a role equivalent of key-value lists, otherwise I'd recommend using *that* instead.</sub>

Comment: OK, so it seems that using ´<dl>´ wouldn't make more sense, and since using a wrapper like in my example would be invalid, I would have to use multiple ´<dl>´ anyway - which doesn't seem to be much better either. And as I really do not want to use tables here, I think I stick to my existing markup, which already just consists of `<div>` layers. So thank you, think this question is answered.